# How to develop ad and ad free version of an app in Android Studio?

Tags: android, ads

I have been wondering what's the best way of developing one app with 2 versions. One with ads and one ad free. Should I make 2 git branches, for the paid one and for the free one, or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your build.gradle file add this

```
productFlavors {
    free {

    }

    paid {

    }
}
```

Comment: Just take a look at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html